# Why does my browser page freeze when making a Google Sheets api (v4) call in my Unity WebGL build?

Tags: google-sheets, webgl, google-sheets-api, google-workspace, unity-webgl

recently I've been involved in a game project where some data of the player needs to be collected and stored centrally. Due to unavailability of a database, we're using Google Sheets to store the data (just a bit of text describing the choices they made in-game in a row of cells (per player))

Using the Google Sheets API (v4) in Unity, I've managed to make this data transfer work, but it only works in the Editor and as a Standalone build, but not in WebGL, which is the target platform.

At first there was an issue with a file I had in StreamingAssets, which I resolved, but now whenever I try to send (test) data to the Google Sheet in WebGL, the page becomes unresponsive and freezes.
As far as I know, there are no Exceptions.

**So my question would be: Why doesn't the call to Google Sheet work specifically in WebGL scenario? Is it a build issue? Or a different issue? (It also doesn't work in Microsoft Edge, so it doesn't seem a browser issue). How can I resolve this?**

Due to safety, I can't share the entire SheetWriter class, but the only things I haven't shared are the credentials and the Sheets' ID

```cs
    private static SheetsService service;

    static SheetWriter()
    {
        ServiceAccountCredential credential = GoogleCredential.FromJson(cJson).UnderlyingCredential as ServiceAccountCredential;

        service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential
        });
    }

    public void WriteToSheet(IList<IList<object>> valueData)
    {
        ValueRange range = new ValueRange();
        range.Values = valueData;
        range.MajorDimension = "ROWS";
        SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.AppendRequest request = service.Spreadsheets.Values.Append(range, spreadsheetId, "A4:K4");
        request.ValueInputOption = SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.AppendRequest.ValueInputOptionEnum.RAW; 

        AppendValuesResponse response = request.Execute();
    }
```

This is fairly simple and straightforward, but I find it strange that it only doesn't work in a WebGL build.

Through some more extensive testing, I've found that it is truly the "request.Execute()" function that's either not being called or not being finished.
By making it async, I was able to pinpoint exactly where it breaks.
I added a logging function before and after this Execute function. The one after is not called.